# How to open a Java desktop tool from another Java application

Tags: java, platform

I have created a Java desk top tool using nebeans platform module.
Now we are creating a common tool from where on click of a button we should be able to launch the existing tool.

Imagine we have a JFrame and two button are present in it.
One is tool1_btn
Second is tool2_btn

Now when I click tool1_btn tool one should pop up.

If I write Like

```
try {
    String line;

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");

    /* java -classpath C:\\projects\\workspace\\testing\\bin test.TestOutput"
     * Create a buffered reader from the Process input stream.
     */
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    /**
     * Loop through the input stream to print the program output into console.
     */
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    /**
     * Finally close the reader
     */
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Will pop up notepad.exe..

But if we give a Java class path for my existing tool jar it will just runs it on the back end.

I want to open the tool as if it is double clicked and opend..Is it possible..Please hlep me..

If my question is not clear inform me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this like this:
File exe = new File(...);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + exe.getAbsolutePath());

Answer (score 1):

You should start by using `ProcessBuilder` over plain `Process`.  Apart from everything else, it allows you to redirect the error stream (to the output stream and other places) as well as specify the starting context for the program (what directory the program will be started in)

Something like...

```
try {
    String line;

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
            "java",
            "-cp",
            "C:\\projects\\workspace\\testing\\bin",
            "test.TestOutput"
    );
    pb.redirectError();

    Process p = pb.start();

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    /**
     * Loop through the input stream to print the program output into console.
     */
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    /**
     * Finally close the reader
     */
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For example...